# Using email image embed as background in django

Tags: django

I'm using [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1507/) for email image embed in django. But I want to use this image as background. 
I'm using this lines in my model:

```
    img_content_id = 'standard.jpg'
    img_data = open('mypath/static/images/standard.jpg', 'rb').read()
    msg = MIMEMultipart(_subtype='related')

    body = 'cid:%s' % img_content_id
    html_content = render_to_string('email/mail.html',
                                      {'email': self.invited, 'url': url, 'current_site':current_site, 'body':body})

    msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.invited])
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg = email_embed_image(msg, img_content_id, img_data)
    msg.send()
```

And using like this in template:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="{{ body }}">
```

But i have two image in mail. (one as attache). What is the right way for Using email image embed as background in django?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more a problem from the mail client.
What mail client do you use ?

See these articles related to Hotmail and Outlook, it might be helpful :

http://email.about.com/od/windowsmailtips/qt/et_inline_image.htm

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/500

Also after reading the code of the snippet you're using, it seems correct to see the image in attachment due to this line : `email.attach(img)`

See the first comment of the snippet, it shows how to use it : using css not a table.

These articles describe the two ways to do it (css and table):

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/

[sending html mail with images not displaying in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173677/sending-html-mail-with-images-not-displaying-in-gmail)

I think it can be helpful for your problem.